# how to revoke access from a user that currently checked out folder using tortoise svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a problem using VisualSVN and tortoise.
we work on multiple projects, I want to grant access to folder FolderA to user UserA and folder FolderB to UserB
but i made a mistake and grant to both FolderA and FolderB to UserA. after that UserA will check out FolderB (that must not have access).
When i revoke access to FolderB from UserA, UserA still has files but he can not make changes in server. when he deletes FolderB from his computer, he can not commit changes, because tortoise want to remove deleted folder FolderB from server (that is not allowed). and also files must not deleted from server because UserB needs them.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `UserA` right-click on `FolderB` in his working copy, chose **"Update to revision"** from the TortoiseSVN context menu. In the update dialog, select **"Exclude"** from the **"Update Depth"** combobox. Then hit the **OK** button.

Answer (score 0):

Ask nicely from *UserA* to delete his working copy via explorer (not svn delete) and checkout *FolderA* again.

Comment: this does not work, because if you delete folder, tortoisesvn tries to delete FolderB from server and because of permission, generates error